# Why will I get "null" when adding to this Array?

Tags: java

Just wondering what is wrong here. The code runs but I continue to get null! Would you be able to assist me on where I'm going wrong?

Much appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StageA {
    
     String id;
     String name;
     String answer;
    
     int MAX_ITEMS = 5;
     int MAX_PATRONS = 0;
     int MAX_LOANS = 4;
     Item [] holdings = new Item [MAX_ITEMS];
     Patron [] Patrons = new Patron[MAX_PATRONS];
     int patronsCount = 0;
     Item i;
    
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
public StageA() {
    

}

public void addItem() {
        
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Add title");
            name = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Add ID");
            id = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Do you wish to continue (Y/N)");
            answer = sc.nextLine();
            
        } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
        
        //create new Item object
        Item i = new Item(name, id);
         int holdingsCount = 0;
            holdings[holdingsCount] = i;
            holdingsCount++;
            
    
            
            System.out.println(holdings[holdingsCount]);            
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StageA newStage1 = new StageA();
        
        newStage1.addItem();
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get null"?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have mispalced the code to add item to the list update your `addItem()` as follows -

```
public void addItem() {

    int holdingsCount = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("Add title");
        name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Add ID");
        id = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Do you wish to continue (Y/N)");
        answer = sc.nextLine();

        //create new Item object
        Item i = new Item(name, id);
        holdings[holdingsCount] = i;
        holdingsCount++;

    } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));





    System.out.println(holdings[holdingsCount]);
}
```

Comment: it shows up as 'null null': public void addItem() {
     
     do
     {
         System.out.println("Add title");
      name = sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Add ID");
      id = sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Do you wish to continue (Y/N)");
      answer = sc.nextLine();
     
       Item i = new Item(name, id);
             holdings[holdingsCount] = i;
             holdingsCount++;
     }
     
        while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
     
     System.out.println(holdings[holdingsCount]);
     
        
 
     }

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues in your `addItem()` method.

1. You need to create the `Item` within your `do-while` loop. Otherwise, you will always create **only one** item with the last `id` and `name` pair provided in the loop.
2. When you print `holdings[holdingsCount]` you have already incremented the `holdingsCount` variable. Then `holdings[holdingsCount]` points to the next array element, which is `null` at that moment. Therefore you need to print the array element **before** incrementing the counter.

```
public void addItem() {

    int holdingsCount = 0;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Add title");
        name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Add ID");
        id = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Do you wish to continue (Y/N)");
        answer = sc.nextLine();

        //create new Item object
        Item i = new Item(name, id);
        holdings[holdingsCount] = i;
        System.out.println(holdings[holdingsCount]);

        holdingsCount++;
        
    } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your addItem method:

```
holdingsCount++;
System.out.println(holdings[holdingsCount]);
```

`holdingsCount++` increases holdingsCount by one unit,so `System.out.println(holdings[holdingsCount])` print the next element of array is null by default.
Change it to

```
 System.out.println(holdings[holdingsCount]);
 holdingsCount++;
```

Comment: Hi friend, thank you for responding. I've changed it to the follwing but still getting the same null message: while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")); {
      
      Item i = new Item(name, id);
      holdings[holdingsCount] = i;
      System.out.println(holdings[holdingsCount]);
       holdingsCount++;
       
   //holdings[holdingsCount] = i;
   //holdingsCount++;
      
     }

Comment: @JockGledhill you can see it https://github.com/dungdg1996/test/blob/master/StageA.java